# Constante global Swift 2

Tags: swift

Ola gostaria de saber como faço para criar um arquivo global de configurações.

Estou usando um **Lib** para fazer consulta http, Alamofire.

Eu gostaria que em qualquer qualquer lugar que em qualquer arquivo que eu chamasse a constante ela fosse acessada.
Exemplo:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, FILECONFIG.CONSTANTEURLGLOBAL, parameters: ["foo": "bar"])
     .responseJSON { response in
         print(response.request)  // original URL request
         print(response.response) // URL response
         print(response.data)     // server data
         print(response.result)   // result of response serialization

         if let JSON = response.result.value {
             print("JSON: \(JSON)")
         }
     }
```

Na parte do código que tem a expressão FILECONFIG.CONSTANTEURLGLOBAL seria a contante que conteria o endereço URL que quero acessar.

Logo o arquivo de configuração seria algo assim:

```
let CONSTANTEURLGLOBAL1 = "http://...."
let CONSTANTEURLGLOBAL2 = "http://...."
let CONSTANTEURLGLOBAL3 = "http://...."
```

Sou extremamente novo em swift então desde já obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar estruturas definidas em um arquivo chamado `Constants.swift`, podendo assim armazenar e acessar as constantes de todo o app de forma limpa:

```
struct Config {
    static let baseURL: NSURL(string: "http://www.example.org/")!
    static let splineReticulatorName = "foobar"
}

struct Color {
    static let primaryColor = UIColor(red: 0.22, green: 0.58, blue: 0.29, alpha: 1.0)
    static let secondaryColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
}


// Uso:

Alamofire.request(.GET, Config.baseURL, parameters: ["foo": "bar"])
     .responseJSON { response in
         print(response.request)  // original URL request
         print(response.response) // URL response
         print(response.data)     // server data
         print(response.result)   // result of response serialization
     if let JSON = response.result.value {
         print("JSON: \(JSON)")
     }
 }
```

---

Você pode encontrar mais no documento que traduzi: [Guia de Estilo Swift - Constantes](https://github.com/iTSangarDEV/Swift-Guia-de-estilo-e-boas-praticas/blob/master/Style%20Guide.md#constantes)

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar uma classe Swift com as configurações que deseja e colocar suas variáveis lá. depois em qualquer classe vc instancia as classe de configurações e acessa a constante que vc quer.

Exemplo:

Cria uma classe Config.swift

coloca a constante let CONSTANTEURLGLOBAL1 = "http://...."

depois na outra classe que vc quer, vc cria: 
var constante = Config()
depois é só chamar: constante.CONSTANTEURLGLOBAL1